# How do I have two canvas elements on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
let vehicle;

let path;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  vehicle = new Vehicle(50, 0);


function draw() {
  background(220);

  path.display();

  vehicle.follow(path);
  vehicle.update();
  vehicle.display();
}

var redLight = 'red'
var yellowLight = 'white'
var greenLight = 'white'
var count = 0;

 

function draw() {
  fill("black")
  rect(140, 70, 110, 250)
  fill(redLight)
  ellipse(195, 120, 60, 60)
  fill("white")
  text("RED", 182, 124)
  fill(yellowLight)
  ellipse(195, 200, 60, 60)
  fill("white")
  text("YELLOW", 171, 205)
  fill(greenLight)
  ellipse(195, 280, 60, 60)
  fill("white")
  text("GREEN", 175, 285)
}
```

Here I have a traffic light and a path and I want them to appear together but I can only make one of them appear so if the traffic light is there it won't show any of the path. How can I change this so that they both appear on the same canvas together.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring two separate `draw()` functions, and so the second one you declare replaces the first one. You need to combine your drawing logic into a single function:

```js
let vehicle;

let path;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  vehicle = new Vehicle(50, 0);

  // initialize path ?!
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  path.display();

  vehicle.follow(path);
  vehicle.update();
  vehicle.display();

  drawTrafficLight();
}

var redLight = 'red'
var yellowLight = 'white'
var greenLight = 'white'
var count = 0;

function drawTrafficLight() {
  fill("black")
  rect(140, 70, 110, 250)
  fill(redLight)
  ellipse(195, 120, 60, 60)
  fill("white")
  text("RED", 182, 124)
  fill(yellowLight)
  ellipse(195, 200, 60, 60)
  fill("white")
  text("YELLOW", 171, 205)
  fill(greenLight)
  ellipse(195, 280, 60, 60)
  fill("white")
  text("GREEN", 175, 285)
}
```